# AWS SES Email Template how to create or update in single command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-templates

I'd like to create an email template during deployment on bitbucket. And update it in future implementations.

Is there an approach for it? Something like creating or update for Cloudformation stack?